# How need to send a value from one React.js page to another page both are opened independently?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I'm new to React.js and I need to send a value from one react page to another,whereas both the pages are opened separately from different links.

```
import React from 'react';
import 'antd/es/input/style/css';
import TextArea from 'antd/lib/input/TextArea';
import { Button} from 'antd';

class EnrollmentToken extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {enterpriseToken : ''}
        }

    getEnterprisetoken = (event) => {
        window.close();
    }

    render() {
        const value = this.props.location.search;
        const token = value.replace('?enterpriseToken=','');
        this.setState = ({enterpriseToken : token});
        return (
            <div>
                <label></label>
                <label class = 'enterprise enterpriseLabel' >Enterprise Token Generated Successfully</label>
                <TextArea size="default" value={token} style={{top : '9px',position : 'relative', width : '700px',left:'20px',}} disabled = {true}/>
                <div><Button onClick={this.getEnterprisetoken}type="primary" style={{top : '80px',position : 'relative', width : '100px',left :'150px'}}>Close</Button></div>
            </div>
        )}
}

export default EnrollmentToken;
```

This is my React.js I need to send the const token value to another React.js file.

Kindly help me in this.

Comment: So you want to share data between two different browser windows? `localStorage` is probably the way to go: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: You could add the value to the local storage, and fetch it in your other window or tab

Comment: If you implement a router , like react-router then see this https://medium.com/@bopaiahmd.mca/how-to-pass-props-using-link-and-navlink-in-react-router-v4-75dc1d9507b4

Answer (score 0):

React state or context only persists on single page/ loses state/memory in refresh, so best way to store token is in local storage:

```
eg: localStorage.setItem("token", token-here) //set token here

const token = localStorage.getItem("token") //get token here
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as props using react-router Link

https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-pass-props-to-link/

But you will lose the data if you refresh the page.

```
                  OR
```

You can use local storage as shown below.

localStorage.setItem("token", enterpriseToken) //set your token

const enterpriseToken = localStorage.getItem("token") //get you token

Answer (score 0):

You can use Context API which is a feature provided with react internally to make data available globally across component tree.The below code illustrates the following:
ref [react context api reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext)

```
  const ThemeContext = React.createContext('light');

  class App extends React.Component {
       render() {
         return (
            <ThemeContext.Provider value="dark">
               <Toolbar />
           </ThemeContext.Provider>
          );
      }
  }


 function Toolbar(props) {
    return (
       <div>
          <ThemedButton />
       </div>
     );
  }

 class ThemedButton extends React.Component {

 static contextType = ThemeContext;
 render() {
     return <Button theme={this.context} />;
    }
 }
```